# Group_Concat with duplicates

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am recently trying to accomplish an aggregation using GROUP_CONCAT in which, for each similar value, I have all duplicate items being queries.

Based on the column invoice_number, I would like to query all the similar items and group_concat them in a string.

However, I am only able to retrieve the first value that is found and group_concat them. I really need to have multiple strings of similar concatenations based on the amount of items that share the same invoice number.

This is my table:

**invoices table**

```
|item_id    |invoice_number |amount |currency|
|-----------|---------------|-------|--------|
|379406     |INV00000046    |52286  |USD     |
|567501     |INV00000046    |52286  |USD     |
|102448     |INV00000390    |0      |USD     |
|1975291    |INV00000390    |0      |USD     |
|62436      |INV00000390    |0      |USD     |
|4067502    |INV00000346    |35112  |EUR     |
|5174950    |INV00000346    |35112  |EUR     |
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
|item_id    |related items          |amount |currency|
|-----------|-----------------------|-------|--------|
|379406     |379406,567501          |52286  |USD     |
|567501     |379406,567501          |52286  |USD     |
|102448     |102448,1975291,62436   |0      |USD     |
|1975291    |102448,1975291,62436   |0      |USD     |
|62436      |102448,1975291,62436   |0      |USD     |
|4067502    |4067502,5174950        |35112  |EUR     |
|5174950    |4067502,5174950        |35112  |EUR     |
```

The query that I wrote is:

```
SELECT
  item_id,
  invoice_number, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(item_id) as shared_item_ids, 
  ROUND(AVG(amount)/100,2) as invoice_amount, 
  currency
FROM
  invoices    
GROUP BY 
  invoice_number, 
  currency
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join the table with itself, using invoice_number as key.

```
SELECT
   invoices.item_id,
   invoices.invoice_number,
   GROUP_CONCAT(related.item_id) as shared_item_ids,
   ROUND(AVG(amount)/100,2) as invoice_amount, 
   currency
FROM invoices
JOIN invoices related ON related.invoice_number = invoices.invoice_number
GROUP BY invoices.item_id
```

Comment: Sadly I am getting the group_concat happening twice per row, and not having each item_id with the same combination.

Comment: Sorry wrong group by (you need to group by item_id).

Comment: @rlanvin what is different with my answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just used a Distinct in the group_concat in order to avoid multiple occurences. It works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

try this sql, hope it will help you.

```
SELECT invoices.item_id, 
 ROUND(AVG(invoices.amount)/100,2) AS invoice_amount,
 invoices.currency, GROUP_CONCAT(relation_table.item_id) AS related items
FROM invoices
LEFT JOIN invoices relation_table ON 
relation_table.invoice_number = invoices.invoice_number
GROUP BY invoices.item_id
```

if you have problem then inform me

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I had in mind. I am getting the group_concat of invoice_numbers instead of a group_concat of item_ids that share the same invoice number :8

Comment: @HeberBrandao please check now